# get first value of a dropdown selected jQuery on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I know this is kinda basic but I'm struggling to get the result I want.

I have a dropdown which gets populated by a list, I want to have the first option selected as soon as the page loads.

```
self.obtenerZafra = function () {
    var url = pathApi + "apizafra/getzafraactivo";
    $.getJSON(url)
        .done(function (data) {

          //  var idZafraAct = 0;

            if (data["estatus"]) {
                // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                self.listaZafra(data["resultado"]);


                $("#IDZafra").val(item.IDZafra).trigger("change");

            } else {
                mostrarToastr(data["mensaje"], "E");
            }
        }).fail(function (d) {
            enableBottonForm();
            mostrarToastr(d.responseText, "E");
        });
}
```

Comment: `("#IDZafra").val(item.IDZafra)` I do not see `item` defined.  Also you stated what you wanted, but not specifically what part of your code is not doing what you want.

Comment: if just the first value should be checked, there is no reason set value before trigger.
What if only `$("#IDZafra").trigger("change");` left?